# Sistema de rutas personalizadas en PHP

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un proyecto PHP sin Frameworks. Tengo un sistema de rutas personalizado. En la raíz del proyecto tengo un archivo llamado `Routes.php` que contiene el siguiente código:

```
$Routes = [
    '/'                 => 'resources/views/Dashboard.php',
    '/login'            => 'resources/views/Login.php',
    '/clientes'         => 'resources/views/Clientes.php',
    '/empleado'         => 'resources/views/Empleados.php',
    '/empleado/editar'  => 'resources/views/Empleados-Editar.php',
];

function resolveRoute($Url, $Routes) {
    if (array_key_exists($Url, $Routes)) {
        return $Routes[$Url];
    } else {
        return '404.php';
    }
}
```

El archivo `index.php` en la raíz del proyecto tiene este código:

```
session_start();
require_once('Routes.php');

$Url    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$View   = resolveRoute($Url, $Routes);

require_once($View);
```

Y el archivo `.htaccess` tiene este código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Si quiero pasar un parámetro por URL a `/empleado/editar`, como puedo lograrlo? Ejemplo: `/empleado/editar/123`

Comment: por que quieres re-inventar la rueda XD

Comment: lo que estas haciendo complica todo... por que mejor no usas namespaces???

Comment: Es un proyecto que ya esta andando, en el cual no utilizan ningún Framework, es un desarrollo PHP nativo (por así decirlo). Antes se editaba desde un PopUp en la misma pagina, pero ahora quieren separarlo, por eso pido ayuda.

Comment: Se puede lograr lo que quieres de manera bastante simple. Si has escrito tú mismo, o al menos entiendes bien el código que llevas hasta ahora, no veo por qué necesitas ayuda en escribir el resto del código que haría falta. Podrías intentarlo y, si tienes algún inconveniente, ya con el código que has intentado, editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces complica cualquier desarrollo por que no hay nada parecido o estandarizado, el principal problema es el no usar `Autoloaders`... peor vamos a por esa solucion que se esquiva de nuestras manos.

`As-IS:` no he tenido chance de probarlo.

- Debemos primero modificar el `array` por que lo que tiene no tiene el alcance necesario para pasar parametros:

```
$Routes = [
    '/'                 => 'resources/views/Dashboard.php',
    '/login'            => 'resources/views/Login.php',
    '/clientes'         => 'resources/views/Clientes.php',
    '/empleado'         => 'resources/views/Empleados.php',
    '/empleado/editar/(\d+)'  => 'resources/views/Empleados-Editar.php',
];
```

Nota: he añadido `(\d+)` al final de la ruta `/empleado/editar/` para capturar un número como parámetro. Puedes ajustarlo según tus necesidades.

- Como Segundo Punto creo combeniente modificar la funcion para que tenga la capacidad de devolver los parametros:

```
function resolveRoute($Url, $Routes) {
    foreach ($Routes as $route => $view) {
        if (preg_match("#^$route$#", $Url, $matches)) {
            // Si hay coincidencia con la ruta, retorna la vista y los parámetros
            array_shift($matches); // Elimina el primer elemento que es la URL completa
            return ['view' => $view, 'params' => $matches];
        }
    }

    // Si no hay coincidencia, retorna una vista de error
    return ['view' => '404.php', 'params' => []];
}
```

- por ultimo toca modificar tambien el archivo `index.php`

```
session_start();
require_once('Routes.php');

$Url    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$routeInfo = resolveRoute($Url, $Routes);

$View   = $routeInfo['view'];
$Params = $routeInfo['params'];

require_once($View);
```

En la vista `Empleados-Editar.php`, puedes acceder a los parámetros mediante la variable `$Params`. Por ejemplo, si la URL es `/empleado/editar/123`, `$Params` contendrá el valor `123`.

Todo esto soluciona tu problema, pero genera problemas de escalabilidad al final para estudiar es un buen ejercicio, pero recomendaria que te pases a algo orientado a objetos, con entidades y un sistema amigable de rutas.

Comment: Funciona! Mil gracias. Simplemente toca mostrar la variable así ```echo $Params[0];``` porque ```$Params``` es un Array.

Comment: Aqui el problema que he detectado despues de varias horas es que: `if (preg_match("#^$route$#", $Url, $matches)) {` puede encontrar 2 rutas similares en tu array ... y el sistema no sabria a cual entrar ...

Comment: entonces como te decia depende mucho de lo que estes haciendo y del mantenimiento y al mismo tiempo ese mantenimiento puede ser complicado en la medida que cresca el proyecto... (problemas de escalabilidad)